# Setup projects on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, visual-studio-2022

In Visual studio 2019 and earlier versions Setup projects were part of the project templates I could add to any solution.
Now I've tried to open an old solution in VS 2022 and it says there is no compatibility for this kind of project.

Is that so, or am I missing something? Is there anything I can do about it?

I know there are some new solutions for installers integrated with VS, but Setup project just works for me and I never felt the need to change.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2022 support for Visual Studio Installer Projects must now be installed as an official Microsoft extension from here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects

I found this by googling "Visual Studio 2022 Installer Project".

Comment: Looks like it's been the same in every version after VS 2015. I already installed it long time ago for VS2017 and it also worked for VS 2019 so I totally forgot.

Comment: Also, from inside VS2022, the menu `Extensions / Manage Extensions` then search for `Setup` and select `Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022`.